# Bit twiddle help: Expanding bits to follow a given bitmask

Tags: algorithm, cuda, bit-manipulation

I'm interested in a fast method for "expanding bits," which can be defined as the following:

1. Let *B* be a binary number with *n* bits, i.e. *B* \in {0,1}^*n*
2. Let *P* be the position of all 1/true bits in *B*, i.e. `1 << p[i] & B == 1`, and |*P*|=*k*
3. For another given number, *A* \in {0,1}^*k*, let *Ap* be the bit-expanded form of *A* given *B*, such that `Ap[j] == A[j] << p[j]`.
4. The result of the "bit expansion" is *Ap*.

A couple examples:

- Given *B*: 00**1**0 **111**0, *A*: 0110, then *Ap* should be 00**0**0 **110**0
- Given *B*: **1**00**1** **1**00**1**, *A*: 1101, then *Ap* should be **1**00**1** **0**00**1**

Following is a straightforward algorithm, but I can't help shake the feeling that there's a faster/easier way to do this.

```
unsigned int expand_bits(unsigned int A, unsigned int B, int n) {
  int k = popcount(B); // cuda function, but there are good methods for this
  unsigned int Ap = 0;
  int j = k-1;
  // Starting at the most significant bit,
  for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    Ap <<= 1;
    // if B is 1, add the value at A[j] to Ap, decrement j. 
    if (B & (1 << i)) {
      Ap += (A >> j--) & 1;
    }
  }
  return Ap;
}
```

Comment: This looks like the functionality of the `PDEP` instruction in the AVX extension to the x86 instruction set (which is also exposed as an intrinsic). I am not aware of a GPU instruction with similar functionality on NVIDIA GPUs, and there is no CUDA intrinsic for this. Do you need this functionality emulated in its full generality, or are you actually looking at a specific, more narrowly defined, instance of such a bit deposition?

Comment: Could you clarify the specification? From what I gather, `A` is the operand whose bits are to be deposited, `B` is the mask controlling the destination bit of each deposited bit. What exactly is the function of `n`?  Since `B` is likely to have some sparseness, it would seem best to iterate over the 1-bits in `B`, starting at the least significant end.

Comment: @njuffa I just looked up the `PDEP` and `PEXT` instructions, and it looks closer to the `PEXT` instruction. In regard to your other question, I need this functionality in its full. The values of `B` will range from `0` to `~0`, but I will only care about values of `k` that are lower than a given value. The value of `n` is just the number of bits for a number--32 for `uint32_t` or  16 for `short`.

Comment: The examples you gave in the question correspond to `PDEP`; I also ran these two examples through my code below prior to posting my answer: `pdep (0x6, 0x2e) = 0c; pdep (0xd, 0x99) = 91`. Since `n` seems to be just the number of bits in the operands, it is not needed. If you need versions for various operand types you can just create overloaded versions using a template, as CUDA is a subset of C++.

Comment: @njuffa you are correct. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question appears to be asking for a CUDA emulation of the BMI2 instruction `PDEP`, which takes a source operand `a`, and deposits its bits based on the positions of the 1-bits of a mask `b`. There is no hardware support for an identical, or a similar, operation on currently shipping GPUs; that is, up to and including the Maxwell architecture.

I am assuming, based on the two examples given, that the mask `b` in general is sparse, and that we can minimize work by only iterating over the 1-bits of `b`. This could cause divergent branches on the GPU, but the exact trade-off in performance is unknown without knowledge of a specific use case. For now, I am assuming that the exploitation of sparsity in the mask `b` has a stronger positive influence on performance compared to the negative impact of divergence.

In the emulation code below, I have reduced the use of potentially "expensive" shift operations, instead relying mostly on simple ALU instructions. On various GPUs, shift instructions are executed with lower throughput than simple integer arithmetic. I have retained a single  shift, *off the critical path* through the code, to avoid becoming execution limited by the arithmetic units. If desired, the expression `1U << i` can be replaced by addition: introduce a variable `m` that is initialized to `1` before the loop and doubled each time through the loop.

The basic idea is to isolate each 1-bit of mask `b` in turn (starting at the least significant end), AND it with the value of the *i*-th bit of `a`, and incorporate the result into the expanded destination. After a 1-bit from `b` has been used, we remove it from the mask, and iterate until the mask becomes zero.

In order to avoid shifting the *i*-th bit of `a` into place, we simply isolate it and then replicate its value to all more significant bits by simple negation, taking advantage of the two's complement representation of integers.

```c++
/* Emulate PDEP: deposit the bits of 'a' (starting with the least significant 
   bit) at the positions indicated by the set bits of the mask stored in 'b'.
*/
__device__ unsigned int my_pdep (unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
    unsigned int l, s, r = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; b; i++) { // iterate over 1-bits in mask, until mask becomes 0
        l = b & (0 - b); // extract mask's least significant 1-bit
        b = b ^ l; // clear mask's least significant 1-bit
        s = 0 - (a & (1U << i)); // spread i-th bit of 'a' to more signif. bits
        r = r | (l & s); // deposit i-th bit of 'a' at position of mask's 1-bit
    }
    return r;
}
```

The variant without any shift operations alluded to above looks as follows:

```c++
/* Emulate PDEP: deposit the bits of 'a' (starting with the least significant 
   bit) at the positions indicated by the set bits of the mask stored in 'b'.
*/
__device__ unsigned int my_pdep (unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
    unsigned int l, s, r = 0, m = 1;
    while (b) { // iterate over 1-bits in mask, until mask becomes 0
        l = b & (0 - b); // extract mask's least significant 1-bit
        b = b ^ l; // clear mask's least significant 1-bit
        s = 0 - (a & m); // spread i-th bit of 'a' to more significant bits
        r = r | (l & s); // deposit i-th bit of 'a' at position of mask's 1-bit
        m = m + m; // mask for next bit of 'a'
    }
    return r;
}
```

In comments below, @Evgeny Kluev pointed to a shift-free `PDEP` emulation at the [chessprogramming wiki](https://www.chessprogramming.org/BMI2#Serial_Implementation) that looks *potentially faster* than either of my two implementations above; it seems worth a try.

Comment: Almost the same algorithm is published on [chessprogramming](https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/BMI2). But they use no shift instructions at all.