# _pdep_u32 in GLSL / HLSL / SPIR-V

Tags: opengl, bit-manipulation, glsl, vulkan, spir-v

I need to interleave* the bits of three unsigned integers in a GLSL program that will be compiled to SPIR-V.
In C, I would use the intrinsic _pdep_u32 but I can't find something like that in the OpenGL reference. Does it exist with some other name? Alternatively, does it exist in HLSL or in raw SPIR-V?
I am aware that there is a tool for converting LLVM IR to SPIR-V. Is it possible to use it to generate _pdep_u32-equivalent bytecode?
Otherwise, can this behavior be implemented in some other way that is also *very* fast?

*That is, the bits from the 32-bit integers A, B and C must appear in the order ABCABC...etc

Comment: I assume you are aware that `_pdep_u32` is not standard C, but a machine-specific *intrinsic* specifically for x86_64 platforms? That makes it unlikely to exist in standard GLSL or HSL, and I am not aware of anything functionally similar in those languages nor the underlying GPU hardware.

Comment: I provided a `PDEP` emulation for CUDA in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35881440/780717)

Comment: Oh sorry, I focused too much on _pdep_u32 in the question when I what I actually want is the functionality. I will look into your CUDA code later. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: It's similar to [interleave the bits of 3 ints](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1024754/555045)