# What is a fast fallback algorithm which emulates PDEP and PEXT in software?

Tags: c++, optimization, x86, bit-manipulation, bmi

I want to create a wrapper around the x86 instructions [PDEP (Parallel Bit Deposit)](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pdep) and [PEXT (Parallel Bit Extract)](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pext).
On architectures where these aren't available (and the corresponding intrinsics aren't either), I need a fast fallback implementation.

The naive algorithms for 32-bit integers looks as follows:

```cpp
constexpr std::uint32_t bit_deposit(std::uint32_t src, std::uint32_t mask) {
    std::uint32_t result = 0;
    for (std::uint32_t src_pos = 0, mask_pos = 0; mask_pos != 32; ++mask_pos) {
        if (mask >> mask_pos & 1) {
            result |= (src >> src_pos++ & 1) << mask_pos;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

static_assert(bit_deposit(0b000, 0b000000) == 0b000000);
static_assert(bit_deposit(0b101, 0b101010) == 0b100010);
static_assert(bit_deposit(0b111, 0b101010) == 0b101010);
```

```cpp
constexpr std::uint32_t bit_extract(std::uint32_t src, std::uint32_t mask) {
    std::uint32_t result = 0;
    for (std::uint32_t src_pos = 0, mask_pos = 0; mask_pos != 32; ++mask_pos) {
        if (mask >> mask_pos & 1) {
            result |= (src >> mask_pos & 1) << src_pos++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

static_assert(bit_extract(0b000000, 0b000000) == 0b000);
static_assert(bit_extract(0b100010, 0b101010) == 0b101);
static_assert(bit_extract(0b101010, 0b101010) == 0b111);
```

Is there a way that you can significantly improve this?
The current algorithm is O(n), and I suspect there is a O(log n) solution.

For a lot of other bit manipulation ops, there is logarithmic algorithm (multi-bit shift from single-bit shift, populatin count, round to next power of two, etc.).
Therefore, I suspect that something similar exists for bit-deposit and bit-extract.

Comment: Existing Q&As about emulating one and/or the other: [Standard C++11 code equivalent to the PEXT Haswell instruction (and likely to be optimized by compiler)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21144237) and [C++ PEXT/PDEP implementations](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/278954) (Still nothing a compiler can recognize, just looping over bits) and similarly [Bit twiddle help: Expanding bits to follow a given bitmask](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35879269) looping on clearing the lowest-set bit in one input.

Comment: Compress/expand is I think a primitive operation that can't easily be composed from other building-blocks.  That's why `pdep`/`pext` exist, along with AVX-512 `vpexpand` / `vpcompress`  (same thing for vector elements according to a k mask) for left-packing; with x86-64-v3, (*[AVX2 what is the most efficient way to pack left based on a mask?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36932240)*), the best I or anyone else has come up with is a way to use pext to pack integer indices and generate a shuffle-control from it.

Comment: @PeterCordes I suspected that you can't easily build it from other things too. I'm working on a proposal to add `std::deposit_bits` to C++26, and having a non-naive fallback implementation would be nice for that

Comment: By the way on platforms without `pext/pdep` but with proper SIMD, you may be able to implement these fairly efficiently in SIMD. For example AVX512 can do it (expand every bit to a byte, `vpexpandb`, compress back to a mask) but every processor with AVX512 also has `pext` and `pdep` anyway.

Comment: @harold: Do ARM SVE or RISC-V vector extensions have expand / left-pack instructions to go with their mask support the way AVX-512 does?

Comment: @PeterCordes SVE has `bext/bdep` so just use that, RISC-V-V has `vcompress.vm` which may be useful and there's a note in the spec for how to build ` vdecompress` (which it doesn't directly have) in terms of a couple of other instructions

Answer (score 5):

In Hacker's Delight chapter 7, rearranging bits and bytes, there is this implementation for expand:

```
unsigned expand(unsigned x, unsigned m) {
    unsigned m0, mk, mp, mv, t;
    unsigned array[5];
    int i;
    m0 = m; // Save original mask.
    mk = ~m << 1; // We will count 0's to right.
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        mp = mk ^ (mk << 1); // Parallel suffix.
        mp = mp ^ (mp << 2);
        mp = mp ^ (mp << 4);
        mp = mp ^ (mp << 8);
        mp = mp ^ (mp << 16);
        mv = mp & m; // Bits to move.
        array[i] = mv;
        m = (m ^ mv) | (mv >> (1 << i)); // Compress m.
        mk = mk & ~mp;
    }
    for (i = 4; i >= 0; i--) {
        mv = array[i];
        t = x << (1 << i);
        x = (x & ~mv) | (t & mv);
    }
    return x & m0; // Clear out extraneous bits.
}
```

And this implementation for compress:

```
unsigned compress(unsigned x, unsigned m) {
    unsigned mk, mp, mv, t;
    int i;
    x = x & m; // Clear irrelevant bits.
    mk = ~m << 1; // We will count 0's to right.
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        mp = mk ^ (mk << 1); // Parallel suffix.
        mp = mp ^ (mp << 2);
        mp = mp ^ (mp << 4);
        mp = mp ^ (mp << 8);
        mp = mp ^ (mp << 16);
        mv = mp & m; // Bits to move.
        m = m ^ mv | (mv >> (1 << i)); // Compress m.
        t = x & mv;
        x = x ^ t | (t >> (1 << i)); // Compress x.
        mk = mk & ~mp;
    }
    return x;
}
```

These doesn't make `k` iterations for a `k`-bit integer, but I don't know whether these are actually a good way to do it. I've heard a rumour that you can do better, but I haven't heard *how*, maybe it's not even true.

Comment: I benchmarked these at more than 3x faster than the naive O(n) versions, but still of the order of 100 cycles (Ivy Bridge Xeon), so quite slow operations.

Comment: @SimonGoater: On Skylake, a non-inline function call to `compress` is about 49x slower for throughput than 1/clock `_pext_u32`.  (GCC `-O3 -march=skylake -mno-bmi` fully unrolls, and it's hot in uop cache for this microbenchark.  BMI1 `andn` instructions make it *slightly* faster 49.12x slower instead of 49.75x, replacing `mov`/`and`/not` or `mov`/`not`/`and` a few times, but IPC drops.)  https://godbolt.org/z/9ve59MGvK has my `perf stat` results and uiCA uop counts / predictions.  (Apparently there's a long enough dep chain that SKL can't find all the ILP across independent calls.)

Comment: `expand` is slightly slower than `compress`, like `5,323,358,496` cycles instead of `4,987,922,399`, for 100M iters in a loop making a non-inline call, for GCC13 `-march=skylake -mno-bmi`.  2.61 IPC

Answer (score 3):

The fast bit manipulation operations work based on divide-and-conquer.

For bit extract, that's feasible, you can split the array in half, do the operation on each half, and keeping track of the number of outputs from each half, you can splice together the packed results.

For bit deposit, you have to start by splitting the packed input... which requires already having found the density of active elements in each half of the distribution.  That's a popcount, which you already have O(lg N) operation for, but if you naively call popcount you'll have to do it O(N) times.  Instead you'll have to keep track of all the partial sums.  By the time you do that, the straightforward approach is probably faster.

---

Note: The well-known bit tricks such as fast popcount aren't actually O(lg N), but O(N/k lg k), where N is the total number of bits and k is the width of the ALU... which is still O(N).  Since you aren't actually getting the speedup on BigInteger inputs, there's no asymptotic benefit.  Whether you get any speedup at all then depends greatly on the constant factor, which tends to hurt "clever solutions" which do parallel computation but need a (non-trivial) reduction step.

Answer (score 3):

Compress/expand is I think a primitive operation that can't easily or efficiently be composed from other building-blocks in the general case for an unknown mask.  Ben Voigt's answer has some good insight into why we should expect this to remain an unsolved problem.

It's only a good idea to use a general-case implementation if you know you'll get true hardware support, or **if that implementation is able to optimize to something much simpler for some compile-time-constant masks**.  (Or as a slow compat fallback for portability and testing in code that's intended to run only on platforms known to have fast support.)

But anyway, I think a useful criterion or goal for a proposed library implementations is how non-terrible it is with regular patterns like `0x0f0f0f0f` to expand or pack nibbles to bytes.  Optimizations like compiling a `mask=0x80808080` pext into `movd xmm0, edi` / `pmovmskb eax, xmm0` would be up to the compiler, probably not a lot we can do to help with that in a scalar implementation.

---

Fast HW support:

- Intel with BMI2 (P-cores since Haswell, E-cores since Gracemont: 1 uop, 3c latency, 1c throughput)
- AMD since Zen 3, same as Intel. (Zen 2, Zen 1, and Excavator have disastrously slow microcoded `pext`/`pdep` with a data-dependent number of uops, with 52 cycle throughput cost being possible, and that might not even be the worst case, IDK.  So unfortunately the BMI2 feature bit doesn't mean it's practically worth using.)
- AArch64 with SVE2 BITPERM can do this on each 8, 16, 32 or [64-bit](https://dougallj.github.io/asil/doc/bdep_z_zz_64.html) element of a vector.  For scalar integer use-cases, you'd need to get data into and back out of a vector reg.
  ([Cortex-A710's opt guide](https://documentation-service.arm.com/static/61ba21e676bb7f0e683c2d42?token=) says `bext`/`bdep`/`bgrp` are 6c latency, one per 2 cycle throughput.)  An [intro to SVE2 guide](https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Arm%20Developer%20Community/PDF/102340_0001_02_en_introduction-to-sve2.pdf?revision=b208e56b-6569-4ae2-b6f3-cd7d5d1ecac3) mentions HPC genomics as a use-case, perhaps for packing/unpacking 2-bit per base DNA sequences, or 6-bit codons (3 DNA bases).
- RISC-V extension V can do `vcompress.vm` which is the equivalent operation on vector elements, like AVX-512 `vpcompressb`.  So you could expand the bits of one input to 0/-1 vector elements and use the other as a compress mask, then compare/test back into an integer bitmask result.
  [@harold commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77834169/what-is-a-fast-fallback-algorithm-which-emulates-pdep-and-pext-in-software#comment137227051_77834169) *there's a note in the spec for how to build `vdecompress` (which it doesn't directly have) in terms of a couple of other instructions*.

So already there's at least three mainstream ISAs with hardware support for this primitive operation.

> I'm working on a proposal to add `std::deposit_bits` to C++26

It's certainly a good idea to lay the groundwork for portable code to take advantage of this primitive operation by getting it into C++26 even if it's not widely available outside x86 yet.  Unlike with `std::countr_zero` / `std::countl_zero` where C++20 was 35 years late (386 `bsf`/`bsr`, ARM `clz` or `rbit`+`clz`, [widespread across many ISAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set)), or like `std::popcount`, which at least was portably exposed by good library implementations of `std::bitset<>::count`.

Even if C++26 comes out in 2026, not all projects will be ready to switch, so with a couple more years a larger fraction of x86 hardware still in use will support `-march=x86-64-v3` with fast (not slow microcoded) `pdep`/`pext`.

ARM has had `rbit` (bit-reverse) for a very long time but it's not common on other ISAs.  Still, [Rust has a builtin for it](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#method.reverse_bits), `i32.reverse_bits()`, taking the sensible approach of having language built-ins for many simple things that *any* ISAs have, instead of needing target-specific intrinsics or recognizing a loop idiom to get efficient asm.  (Rust doesn't have `pdep` / `pext` builtins, though.)

C++'s `<bit>` header has a byte-reverse but not a bit-reverse function.  There are platform-specific ways to do it fast, such as x86 with SSSE3 `pshufb` to unpack 8 bytes to 16 nibbles and use a lookup table, but it's not plausible to take advantage of that from portable code. (And presumably a log(n) bithack is possible with lots of masks, as a generic fallback implementation.)  So if we're adding stuff to `<bit>` in C++20, that's another good one to consider.

---

As further practical evidence of `pdep`/`pext` being hard to synthesize from "standard" ops like boolean and add/sub carry-propagation, AMD Zen 2 and earlier had very slow microcoded `pdep`/`pext`, with a data-dependent number of uops.  https://uops.info/ measured 119 / [133](https://uops.info/html-tp/ZEN2/PEXT_R64_R64_M64-Measurements.html) uops respectively for the 64-bit memory-source version with one per ~50 cycle throughput.  They measured the reg source version at only 6 or 7 uops with 18c throughput, but probably that was just different inputs (initializer code not shown), and 133 uops might not even be the *worst* case, just far from the best.

Many real use-cases involve some known patterns, e.g. perhaps 4-bit groups go together, or the mask is even a constant.  In those cases, there's almost always something faster than Zen 2 microcoded `pdep`/`pext` which software should use instead.

In a few years, Zen 2 will be sufficiently obsolete that some software compiled for `-march=x86-64-v3` can reasonably assume `pdep`/`pext` to be usable, but any dynamic CPU dispatching should check CPU version and not use a `pdep`/`pext` version on Zen2 and earlier even though BMI2 is available.

The fact that this is hard are why `pdep`/`pext` exist, along with AVX-512 `vpexpand` / `vpcompress` - same thing for vector elements according to a `k` mask.   For left-packing with x86-64-v3 (*[AVX2 what is the most efficient way to pack left based on a mask?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36932240)*), the best I or anyone else has come up with is a way to use `pext` to pack integer indices and generate a shuffle-control from it.

---

Other Q&As with various implementations of `pext` and/or `pdep`, none with log2(width) number of steps.  Usually involving something like `mask &= (mask - 1);` clear lowest-set bit to loop over the `1`s in one of the inputs.

- [Standard C++11 code equivalent to the PEXT Haswell instruction (and likely to be optimized by compiler)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21144237/standard-c11-code-equivalent-to-the-pext-haswell-instruction-and-likely-to-be) / https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/278954/c-pext-pdep-implementations - still a no on idiom-recognition or efficiency.
- [Bit twiddle help: Expanding bits to follow a given bitmask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35879269/bit-twiddle-help-expanding-bits-to-follow-a-given-bitmask) (njuffa's attempt; he comments that https://www.chessprogramming.org/BMI2#Serial_Implementation looks probably faster)
- [Emulate AVX512 VPCOMPESSB byte packing without AVX512_VBMI2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61717613/emulate-avx512-vpcompessb-byte-packing-without-avx512-vbmi2) (the same problem but for vector elements.) - unanswered

If the answers here are actually more efficient, some of those should get closed as a duplicate of this.

Comment: By the way [the draft of the aforementioned C++26 proposal can be found here](https://github.com/Eisenwave/cpp-proposals/blob/master/src/bit-deposit-extract-reverse.html).

Comment: I don't have time to read all of this answer now; I'm going to bed. Thanks so far, I'll probably integrate some of it in the section about hardware support.

Comment: @Peter Cordes I looked at the literature on efficient hardware implementation of these operations, and I think this *might* inspire somewhat more efficient software implementations. For example, one decomposition is into a very regular structure of log2(N) layers of butterfly operations. The expensive part seems to be generating the control signals for each layer from the mask: this decode work is rather involved when performed in software. I spent some hours playing with this but without success so far; it's a hard problem for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Beating those functions in harold's answer with SSE is a challenge. I have to admit, I don't understand how those functions work. Maybe if I studied them in more detail, I could figure out a way of vectorising them. I attempted my own solution from scratch instead. I started with a simple naive function,

```
uint32_t pdep32_naive(uint32_t src, uint32_t mask) {
  uint32_t dest = 0;
  uint32_t bit = 1;
  uint32_t kbit = 1;
  while (bit) {
    if (mask & bit) {
        if (src & kbit) dest |= bit;
        kbit <<= 1;
    }
    bit <<= 1;
  }
  return dest;
}
```

them made the code inside the loop branchless.

```
uint32_t pdep32_naive_branchless(uint32_t src, uint32_t mask) {
  uint32_t dest = 0;
  uint32_t bit = 1;
  uint32_t kbit = 1;
  _Bool temp;
  while (bit) {
    temp = ((mask & bit) != 0);
    dest |= bit*((src & kbit) != 0)*temp;
    kbit <<= temp;
    bit <<= 1;
  }
  return dest;
}
```

My vectorisation approach is to take each byte of the mask separately, but to do that I first need the kbits.

```
__m128i getpdep32kbits128(uint32_t mask) {
  uint8_t maskpops[4];
  uint32_t kbits[4];
  mask = mask - ((mask >> 1) & 0x55555555);
  mask = (mask & 0x33333333) + ((mask >> 2) & 0x33333333);
  mask = (mask + (mask >> 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F; 
  maskpops[1] = (mask >> 16) & 0xf;
  maskpops[2] = (mask >> 8) & 0xf;
  maskpops[3] = mask & 0xf;  
  maskpops[2] += maskpops[3];
  maskpops[1] += maskpops[2];
  kbits[3] = 1;
  kbits[2] = 1 << maskpops[3];
  kbits[1] = 1 << maskpops[2];
  kbits[0] = 1 << maskpops[1];
  return _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)kbits);
}
```

If the mask is constant over a lot of pdep() calls, then calculating this only once saves quite a bit of work. Now calculate the vectorised result.

```
uint32_t pdep32_kbits(uint32_t src, uint32_t mask, __m128i kbits128) {
  uint32_t dest[4];
  __m128i dest128 = _mm_setzero_si128();
  __m128i bits128 = _mm_setr_epi32(1 << 24, 1 << 16, 1 << 8, 1);
  __m128i mask128 = _mm_set1_epi32(mask);
  __m128i src128 = _mm_set1_epi32(src);
  __m128i temp128;
  for (int i=0; i<8; i++) {
    temp128 = _mm_cmpeq_epi32(_mm_and_si128(bits128, mask128), _mm_setzero_si128()); 
    dest128 = _mm_or_si128(dest128, _mm_andnot_si128(temp128, _mm_andnot_si128(_mm_cmpeq_epi32(_mm_and_si128(src128, kbits128), _mm_setzero_si128()), bits128)));
    kbits128 = _mm_add_epi32(kbits128, _mm_andnot_si128(temp128, kbits128));
    bits128 = _mm_add_epi32(bits128, bits128);
  }
  _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)dest, dest128);
  return dest[0] | dest[1] | dest[2] | dest[3];
}
```

According to my benchmarks, it is only materially faster (approx. 2x) than the one from Hackers Delight chapter 7 when you have to calculate the kbits infrequently, otherwise the performance is comparable. I though someone might find this useful, or be inspired to have a go themselves at this, the pext() function or 64 bit versions.

NOTE: The vectorised code shown only requires SSE2 support, but benefits from later extensions in compilation, so best to use -march=native and -O3 if you can when compiling.

EDIT: I've been a bit unfair comparing the SSE function to the Hackers Delight function in the case of infrequent updates to the mask. In that case, one could adapt the Hacker's Delight function to work more efficiently also. One way is as follows.

```
typedef struct {
    uint32_t array[5];
    uint32_t mask;
} pdepu32_mask_obj_t;

typedef struct {
    uint32_t mv[5];
    uint32_t mask;
} pextu32_mask_obj_t;

void pext_u32_init(uint32_t m, pextu32_mask_obj_t *mask_obj) {
    uint32_t mk, mp, mv;
    uint32_t i;
    mask_obj->mask = m;
    mk = ~m << 1; // We will count 0's to right.
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        mp = mk ^ (mk << 1); // Parallel suffix.
        mp = mp ^ (mp << 2);
        mp = mp ^ (mp << 4);
        mp = mp ^ (mp << 8);
        mp = mp ^ (mp << 16);
        mv = mp & m; // Bits to move.
        mask_obj->mv[i] = mv; // Bits to move.
        m = (m ^ mv) | (mv >> (1 << i)); // Compress m.
        mk = mk & ~mp;
    }
    return;
}

uint32_t pext_u32_calc(uint32_t x, pextu32_mask_obj_t mask_obj) {
    uint32_t i, t;
    x = x & mask_obj.mask; // Clear irrelevant bits.
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        t = x & mask_obj.mv[i];
        x = (x ^ t) | (t >> (1 << i)); // Compress x.
    }
    return x;
}

void pdep_u32_init(uint32_t m, pdepu32_mask_obj_t *mask_obj) {
    uint32_t mk, mp, mv;
    int32_t i;
    mask_obj->mask = m;
    mk = ~m << 1; // We will count 0's to right.
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        mp = mk ^ (mk << 1); // Parallel suffix.
        mp = mp ^ (mp << 2);
        mp = mp ^ (mp << 4);
        mp = mp ^ (mp << 8);
        mp = mp ^ (mp << 16);
        mv = mp & m; // Bits to move.
        mask_obj->array[i] = mv;
        m = (m ^ mv) | (mv >> (1 << i)); // Compress m.
        mk = mk & ~mp;
    }
    return; 
}

uint32_t pdep_u32_calc(uint32_t x, pdepu32_mask_obj_t mask_obj) {
    uint32_t mv, t;
    uint32_t m = mask_obj.mask;
    int32_t i;
    for (i = 4; i >= 0; i--) {
        mv = mask_obj.array[i];
        t = x << (1 << i);
        x = (x & ~mv) | (t & mv);
    }
    return x & m; // Clear out extraneous bits.
}
```

Then you can use it in the following way.

```
pdepu32_mask_obj_t mask_obj;
pdep_u32_init(mask, &mask_obj);
for (some loop) {
  res = pdep_u32_calc(src, mask_obj);
....}
```

There's a slight performance penalty splitting the function like this if you calculate the mask every call, but when the mask changes infrequently, these are easily the fastest _pdep_u32() and _pext_u32() substitutes implementation I have tested so far at approximately 2.5x faster than doing the whole thing every time.

Comment: To understand the Hacker's Delight versions, you should read the book where they come from. Admittedly, they are pretty obscure. Also, I've been messing around with various functions https://godbolt.org/z/fq1M4zr6q . Perhaps these versions will be helpful.

Comment: There's a good 64bit implementation here https://github.com/zwegner/zp7/blob/master/zp7.c

Answer (score 2):

The code from Hacker's Delight offers better worst-case performance than any other approach I have tried. However, when the mask is sparsely populated on average, simple bit-wise methods will usually provide better performance.

Some months back I needed PDEP functionality on a non-x86 32-bit platform which provides fast hardware implementations of count leading zeros (CLZ) and population count (POPC). This allows iterating over *contiguous groups* of 1-bits in the mask, rather than individual 1-bits. While the processing of a bit group is more expensive than the processing of a bit, there can be at most 16 bit groups in a 32-bit word, and the overall cost when processing in bit groups came out 10% lower than with bit-wise processing in my context. CLZ is needed to determine the position of the least-significant starting bit of the bit group, and POPC is used to determine its length.

I *prototyped* this approach on my Windows system, so the C code shown below uses Windows-specific intrinsics, but these can easily be replaced with corresponding platform- or compiler-specific intrinsics for other environments. For test purposes I built with MSCV (`cl`), Intel Classic (`icl`) and Intel OneAPI (`icx`) compilers.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <intrin.h> // Windows-specific header file for intrinsics

uint32_t my_pdep_u32 (uint32_t src, uint32_t msk)
{
    uint32_t oldmsk, bitgrp, bitgrplsb, grplen, lsbpos, shift, depcnt, res;
    depcnt = 0;
    res = 0;
    while (msk) {
        oldmsk = msk;
        bitgrplsb = (msk & (0 - msk));
        msk = (bitgrplsb + msk) & msk;
        bitgrp = msk ^ oldmsk;
        _BitScanReverse (&lsbpos, bitgrplsb); // lsbpos = 31 - clz (bitgrplsb)
        grplen = __popcnt (bitgrp);
        shift = lsbpos - depcnt;
        depcnt = depcnt + grplen;
        res = res | ((src << shift) & bitgrp);
    }
    return res;
}

#if defined(_WIN32)
#if !defined(WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN)
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif
#include <windows.h>
double second (void)
{
    LARGE_INTEGER t;
    static double oofreq;
    static int checkedForHighResTimer;
    static BOOL hasHighResTimer;

    if (!checkedForHighResTimer) {
        hasHighResTimer = QueryPerformanceFrequency (&t);
        oofreq = 1.0 / (double)t.QuadPart;
        checkedForHighResTimer = 1;
    }
    if (hasHighResTimer) {
        QueryPerformanceCounter (&t);
        return (double)t.QuadPart * oofreq;
    } else {
        return (double)GetTickCount() * 1.0e-3;
    }
}
#elif defined(__linux__) || defined(__APPLE__)
#include <stddef.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
double second (void)
{
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    return (double)tv.tv_sec + (double)tv.tv_usec * 1.0e-6;
}
#else
#error unsupported platform
#endif

// George Marsaglia's KISS PRNG, period 2**123. Newsgroup sci.math, 21 Jan 1999
// Bug fix: Greg Rose, "KISS: A Bit Too Simple" http://eprint.iacr.org/2011/007
static uint32_t kiss_z=362436069, kiss_w=521288629;
static uint32_t kiss_jsr=123456789, kiss_jcong=380116160;
#define znew (kiss_z=36969*(kiss_z&65535)+(kiss_z>>16))
#define wnew (kiss_w=18000*(kiss_w&65535)+(kiss_w>>16))
#define MWC  ((znew<<16)+wnew )
#define SHR3 (kiss_jsr^=(kiss_jsr<<13),kiss_jsr^=(kiss_jsr>>17), \
              kiss_jsr^=(kiss_jsr<<5))
#define CONG (kiss_jcong=69069*kiss_jcong+1234567)
#define KISS ((MWC^CONG)+SHR3)

int main (void)
{
    uint32_t src, msk, res, ref;
    double start, stop;

    start = second();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        msk = KISS;
        printf ("mask=%08x\n", msk);
        src = 0;
        do {
            ref = _pdep_u32 (src, msk);
            res = my_pdep_u32 (src, msk);
            if (res != ref) {
                printf ("msk=%08x src=%08x res=%08x ref=%08x\n", msk, src, res, ref);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            src++;
        } while (src);
    } 
    stop = second();
    printf ("elapsed: %.6f sec\n", stop - start);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: The code from hacker's delight can be turned from O(log² n) to O(log n) using CLMUL. https://github.com/zwegner/zp7 has a working implementation of that. Is your method still better for sparse masks then?

Comment: There is also a trick (to replace clmul) with four 64-bit multiplications and some bitops (doing `((x & (m << i)) * m & (m << i)) * 15` for `i in 0..3` and XORing the results), that's bad on ARM and x64 but maybe on *some* platform there's a point to it?

Comment: @njuffa there is `PMUL` in ARM with SVE, which is the same as `CLMUL`. You need to go through vector registers, but it's there at least. I've posted a version using `CLMUL` as an answer btw.

Comment: @JanSchultke: Just for the record, [SVE does exist in AArch32 state](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/101427/0101/Register-descriptions/Scalable-vector-extensions--SVE--registers), but I expect it'll be a *long* time before embedded processors support it.  128-bit SIMD is still an optional high-end feature for Cortex-M microcontrollers.  [Arm NEON and poly8\_t and poly16\_t](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/33763077) - apparently 32-bit ARMv7 `VMULL.P8` is just 8x8->16-bit but there's an ARMv8 crypto extension for 64x64 -> 128-bit.  ARMv8 `PMUL`/`PMULL`/`PMULL2` may be different

Comment: @JanSchultke: Also [Convert \_mm\_clmulepi64\_si128 to vmull\_{high}\_p64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38553881) . But some of the links from my answer are dead now, and I'm not 100% sure I got everything right.  `vmull_p64` apparently requires NEON + AES features (https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/arch/aarch64/fn.vmull_p64.html), so that's plausible in some embedded use-cases moreso than SVE.  For 32-bit ARM, https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/arch/arm/index.html only mentions `p8` polynomial multiply.

Answer (score 2):

Based on all of the answers and some additional resources, I have worked out a solution myself.

The solution is based on the approach in Hacker's Delight, but is optimized to O(log n) from O(log<sup>2</sup> n) when carry-less multiplication is available.
This complexity analysis of course assumes that any native bitwise operation is O(1).

```cpp
constexpr std::uint32_t bit_extract(std::uint32_t x, std::uint32_t m)
{
    x &= m;
    std::uint32_t mk = ~m << 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < 32; i <<= 1) {
        const std::uint32_t mk_parity = bitwise_inclusive_right_parity(mk); // see below

        const std::uint32_t move = mk_parity & m;
        m = (m ^ move) | (move >> i);

        const std::uint32_t t = x & move;
        x = (x ^ t) | (t >> i);

        mk &= ~mk_parity;
    }
    return x;
}
```

```cpp
constexpr std::uint32_t bit_deposit(std::uint32_t x, std::uint32_t m)
{

    const std::uint32_t initial_m = m;

    std::uint32_t array[5];
    std::uint32_t mk = ~m << 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        const std::uint32_t mk_parity = bitwise_inclusive_right_parity(mk); // see below
        const std::uint32_t move = mk_parity & m;
        m = (m ^ move) | (move >> (1 << i));
        array[i] = move;
        mk &= ~mk_parity;
    }

    for (int i = 5; i-- > 0;) {
        const std::uint32_t move = array[i];
        const std::uint32_t t = x << (1 << i);
        x = (x & ~move) | (t & move);
    }

    return x & initial_m;
}
```

```cpp
#include <immintrin.h>

constexpr std::uint32_t bitwise_inclusive_right_parity(std::uint32_t x)
{
#ifdef __PCLMUL__
    if !consteval {
        const __m128i x_128 = _mm_set_epi64x(0, x);
        const __m128i neg1_128 = _mm_set_epi64x(0, -1);
        const __m128i result_128 = _mm_clmulepi64_si128(x_128, neg1_128, 0);
        return static_cast<std::uint32_t>(_mm_extract_epi64(result_128, 0));
    }
#endif
    // TODO: Use ARM intrinsics if possible.

    for (int i = 1; i < 32; i <<= 1) {
        x ^= x << i;
    }
    return x;
}
```

This code is  simplified and de-templated excerpt. See [eisenwave/cxx26-bit-permutations](https://github.com/Eisenwave/cxx26-bit-permutations) for the full code.

Comment: Nice! I tried this on my Xeon W-2133 (Skylake) with the Intel OneAPI compiler (2023.0.0) and saw about 20% incremental speedup compared to the code pulled straight from Hacker's Delight. I guess I have some studying to do regarding CLMUL.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to PEXT a single byte, there is a pretty fast algorithm using a 2KiB lookup table, two multiplications, an addition and an AND.

It's based on the idea that a single multiplication can encode the sum of a variety of left-shifted elements. For example for the input `abcdefgh` and mask `0b11011101`:

```
           b << 16 = ________________________________________abcdefgh________________
           b << 25 = _______________________________abcdefgh_________________________
           b << 35 = _____________________abcdefgh___________________________________
           b << 44 = ____________abcdefgh____________________________________________
           b << 53 = ___abcdefgh_____________________________________________________
           b << 63 = h_______________________________________________________________

               sum = h__abcdefgh_abcdefgh_abcdefgh__abcdefgh_abcdefgh________________
0x8080808080808080 = 1_______1_______1_______1_______1_______1_______1_______1_______
               tmp = h_______f_______e_______d_______b_______a_______________________
```

This results in a contiguous 1 bit per byte output, in reverse order. Then the high multiplication by `0x80402010080402` followed by an addition of `tmp` reverses this bit sequence and compresses this it back down to a single byte.

```cpp
static uint64_t mulhi64(uint64_t a, uint64_t b) {
    // Replace this by whatever your compiler offers to get the
    // high bits of a 64-bit multiplication.
    return ((__uint128_t) a * (__uint128_t) b) >> 64;
}

uint8_t pext8(uint8_t x, uint8_t m) {
    uint64_t tmp = (uint64_t(x) * MAGIC_LUT[m]) & 0x8080808080808080ull;
    return mulhi64(t, 0x80402010080402) + tmp;
}

static const uint64_t MAGIC_LUT[256] = {
    0x0000000000000000ull, 0x8000000000000000ull, 0x4000000000000000ull, 0x8040000000000000ull,
    0x2000000000000000ull, 0x8020000000000000ull, 0x4020000000000000ull, 0x8040200000000000ull,
    0x1000000000000000ull, 0x8010000000000000ull, 0x4010000000000000ull, 0x8040100000000000ull,
    0x2010000000000000ull, 0x8020100000000000ull, 0x4020100000000000ull, 0x8040201000000000ull,
    0x0800000000000000ull, 0x8008000000000000ull, 0x4008000000000000ull, 0x8040080000000000ull,
    0x2008000000000000ull, 0x8020080000000000ull, 0x4020080000000000ull, 0x8040200800000000ull,
    0x1008000000000000ull, 0x8010080000000000ull, 0x4010080000000000ull, 0x8040100800000000ull,
    0x2010080000000000ull, 0x8020100800000000ull, 0x4020100800000000ull, 0x8040201008000000ull,
    0x0400000000000000ull, 0x8004000000000000ull, 0x4004000000000000ull, 0x8040040000000000ull,
    0x2004000000000000ull, 0x8020040000000000ull, 0x4020040000000000ull, 0x8040200400000000ull,
    0x1004000000000000ull, 0x8010040000000000ull, 0x4010040000000000ull, 0x8040100400000000ull,
    0x2010040000000000ull, 0x8020100400000000ull, 0x4020100400000000ull, 0x8040201004000000ull,
    0x0804000000000000ull, 0x8008040000000000ull, 0x4008040000000000ull, 0x8040080400000000ull,
    0x2008040000000000ull, 0x8020080400000000ull, 0x4020080400000000ull, 0x8040200804000000ull,
    0x1008040000000000ull, 0x8010080400000000ull, 0x4010080400000000ull, 0x8040100804000000ull,
    0x2010080400000000ull, 0x8020100804000000ull, 0x4020100804000000ull, 0x8040201008040000ull,
    0x0200000000000000ull, 0x8002000000000000ull, 0x4002000000000000ull, 0x8040020000000000ull,
    0x2002000000000000ull, 0x8020020000000000ull, 0x4020020000000000ull, 0x8040200200000000ull,
    0x1002000000000000ull, 0x8010020000000000ull, 0x4010020000000000ull, 0x8040100200000000ull,
    0x2010020000000000ull, 0x8020100200000000ull, 0x4020100200000000ull, 0x8040201002000000ull,
    0x0802000000000000ull, 0x8008020000000000ull, 0x4008020000000000ull, 0x8040080200000000ull,
    0x2008020000000000ull, 0x8020080200000000ull, 0x4020080200000000ull, 0x8040200802000000ull,
    0x1008020000000000ull, 0x8010080200000000ull, 0x4010080200000000ull, 0x8040100802000000ull,
    0x2010080200000000ull, 0x8020100802000000ull, 0x4020100802000000ull, 0x8040201008020000ull,
    0x0402000000000000ull, 0x8004020000000000ull, 0x4004020000000000ull, 0x8040040200000000ull,
    0x2004020000000000ull, 0x8020040200000000ull, 0x4020040200000000ull, 0x8040200402000000ull,
    0x1004020000000000ull, 0x8010040200000000ull, 0x4010040200000000ull, 0x8040100402000000ull,
    0x2010040200000000ull, 0x8020100402000000ull, 0x4020100402000000ull, 0x8040201004020000ull,
    0x0804020000000000ull, 0x8008040200000000ull, 0x4008040200000000ull, 0x8040080402000000ull,
    0x2008040200000000ull, 0x8020080402000000ull, 0x4020080402000000ull, 0x8040200804020000ull,
    0x1008040200000000ull, 0x8010080402000000ull, 0x4010080402000000ull, 0x8040100804020000ull,
    0x2010080402000000ull, 0x8020100804020000ull, 0x4020100804020000ull, 0x8040201008040200ull,
    0x0100000000000000ull, 0x8001000000000000ull, 0x4001000000000000ull, 0x8040010000000000ull,
    0x2001000000000000ull, 0x8020010000000000ull, 0x4020010000000000ull, 0x8040200100000000ull,
    0x1001000000000000ull, 0x8010010000000000ull, 0x4010010000000000ull, 0x8040100100000000ull,
    0x2010010000000000ull, 0x8020100100000000ull, 0x4020100100000000ull, 0x8040201001000000ull,
    0x0801000000000000ull, 0x8008010000000000ull, 0x4008010000000000ull, 0x8040080100000000ull,
    0x2008010000000000ull, 0x8020080100000000ull, 0x4020080100000000ull, 0x8040200801000000ull,
    0x1008010000000000ull, 0x8010080100000000ull, 0x4010080100000000ull, 0x8040100801000000ull,
    0x2010080100000000ull, 0x8020100801000000ull, 0x4020100801000000ull, 0x8040201008010000ull,
    0x0401000000000000ull, 0x8004010000000000ull, 0x4004010000000000ull, 0x8040040100000000ull,
    0x2004010000000000ull, 0x8020040100000000ull, 0x4020040100000000ull, 0x8040200401000000ull,
    0x1004010000000000ull, 0x8010040100000000ull, 0x4010040100000000ull, 0x8040100401000000ull,
    0x2010040100000000ull, 0x8020100401000000ull, 0x4020100401000000ull, 0x8040201004010000ull,
    0x0804010000000000ull, 0x8008040100000000ull, 0x4008040100000000ull, 0x8040080401000000ull,
    0x2008040100000000ull, 0x8020080401000000ull, 0x4020080401000000ull, 0x8040200804010000ull,
    0x1008040100000000ull, 0x8010080401000000ull, 0x4010080401000000ull, 0x8040100804010000ull,
    0x2010080401000000ull, 0x8020100804010000ull, 0x4020100804010000ull, 0x8040201008040100ull,
    0x0201000000000000ull, 0x8002010000000000ull, 0x4002010000000000ull, 0x8040020100000000ull,
    0x2002010000000000ull, 0x8020020100000000ull, 0x4020020100000000ull, 0x8040200201000000ull,
    0x1002010000000000ull, 0x8010020100000000ull, 0x4010020100000000ull, 0x8040100201000000ull,
    0x2010020100000000ull, 0x8020100201000000ull, 0x4020100201000000ull, 0x8040201002010000ull,
    0x0802010000000000ull, 0x8008020100000000ull, 0x4008020100000000ull, 0x8040080201000000ull,
    0x2008020100000000ull, 0x8020080201000000ull, 0x4020080201000000ull, 0x8040200802010000ull,
    0x1008020100000000ull, 0x8010080201000000ull, 0x4010080201000000ull, 0x8040100802010000ull,
    0x2010080201000000ull, 0x8020100802010000ull, 0x4020100802010000ull, 0x8040201008020100ull,
    0x0402010000000000ull, 0x8004020100000000ull, 0x4004020100000000ull, 0x8040040201000000ull,
    0x2004020100000000ull, 0x8020040201000000ull, 0x4020040201000000ull, 0x8040200402010000ull,
    0x1004020100000000ull, 0x8010040201000000ull, 0x4010040201000000ull, 0x8040100402010000ull,
    0x2010040201000000ull, 0x8020100402010000ull, 0x4020100402010000ull, 0x8040201004020100ull,
    0x0804020100000000ull, 0x8008040201000000ull, 0x4008040201000000ull, 0x8040080402010000ull,
    0x2008040201000000ull, 0x8020080402010000ull, 0x4020080402010000ull, 0x8040200804020100ull,
    0x1008040201000000ull, 0x8010080402010000ull, 0x4010080402010000ull, 0x8040100804020100ull,
    0x2010080402010000ull, 0x8020100804020100ull, 0x4020100804020100ull, 0x8040201008040201ull,
};
```

The magic lookup table is generated in Python as such:

```py
def gen_magic(m):
    out = 0
    shift = 63
    for i in range(8):
        if m & (1 << i):
            out += 1 << (shift - i)
            shift -= 8
    return out
```

Comment: This solution is kinda neat, but if you're going to need a relatively large lookup table anyway, wouldn't it be better to fully pre-compute all possible results in a big table? You'd need a 65KiB table then.

Comment: @JanSchultke I personally think saving 63KiB of L1 cache is worth two integer multiplications, an add, and a bitand instruction.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the mask parameter constant (or very rarely changed), then lookup tables may help.

You can divide the other parameter by 8 bit portions (or portions of a larger size), look up each part and bitwise-or the result together.

The tables could be computed beforehand at runtime. Or even in compile time if the parameter is known in compile time.

Looking up by parts has some memory footprint, but will make fewer operations than shift-based computation.